# Passing a return value from one array to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

The code below displays individual words from an array when a user clicks the button. I want the previous words to display so I am pushing to a new array. What I would like to do is pass the return value from my_array.randsplice() to a second array so I can display the contents of the second array at the same index position.  What I am trying (unsuccessfully) to do is show a word from one array and the definition of the word from the second array but I cant figure it out. Do I need two arrays to do this or is is possible to splice a multi-dimensional array that contains both sets of data? Any help is appreciated.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Word List</title>
<style>
.wordList {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: green;
}
</style>
<script>
Array.prototype.randsplice = function(){
    var ri = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length);
    var rs = this.splice(ri, 1);
    return rs;  
}
var new_array =[];
var my_array = [' Apple',
        ' Bat',
        ' Car',
        ' Dog',
        ' Elephant',
        ];


function getWord() {
    var result = my_array.randsplice();
    new_array.push(result);
    document.getElementById('word_list').innerHTML = new_array;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">

          <div class="header">
            <h1 id="game_title">Title Here</h1> 
            <hr>
            <button onclick="getWord()">Get Word</button>
            <h2 id="word_list_title">Word List:</h2>
            <h2 id="word_list" class="wordList"> </h2>
          </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is your current code giving you?

Comment: Right now its just displaying one word every time user hits the button until the array is empty. I think I need that rs value to pass to the definition array which i could push to another new array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is an array of objects.

`var dictionary = [
{word: "Apple", meaning: "A red fruit"}, {word: "Bat", meaning: "A nocturnal bird"}
];`

You can then access the word like so:

```
dictionary[0].word    // "Apple"
```

And the meaning like this:

```
dictionary[0].meaning    // "A red fruit"
```

All you need to do to get a "random" word from the dictionary is to replace "0" with the random index. Hope this is clear!

`var ri = Math.floor(Math.random()*dictionary.length);`

`dictionary[ri].word    // Gives a random word`

`dictionary[ri].meaning    // Gives that random words meaning`

```
function getWord() {
var ri = Math.floor(Math.random()*dictionary.length);
document.getElementById('word_list').innerHTML = dictionary[ri].word + ":" + dictionary[ri].meaning;
dictionary.splice(ri, 1);
}
```

Comment: This would be what my guess is as to what the OP is going for, but didn't actually ask.

Comment: Yeah, not sure if this is what the OP wants to do.

Comment: so would the splice look something like: var rs = this.word.splice({ri,1}); I'm not real familiar with javascript; I used to do a fair bit of AS3 but I am ruuuuusty! Thanks.

Comment: What are you looking to splice? Would be great if you explain what is the output / end goal...

Comment: "What I am trying (unsuccessfully) to do is show a word from one array and the definition of the word from the second array but I cant figure it out."

Comment: I'm proposing that you use a single array of objects instead of two different arrays. I've made an edit and added some code at the end - does this help?

Comment: I've rewritten the getWord function to use the array of objects, let me know if this helps

Comment: so if ri is a random value then it could display the same word multiple times  after each button press, right? Thats why i wanted to use a splice - so words aren't repeated.

Comment: Yes, that's right - I've edited it now to include the splice

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Now if I want to append the new word to the old word list I need to do something like: new_array.push(dictionary[ri].word); or something like that, right? (the user would see the word list growing but the definition would only appear for the current word).

Comment: Yes, I think you've got the hang of it :)

Answer (score 0):

This answer features an object with words as key and a meaning. Additionally, the `Array.prototype.randomSplice` returns undefined if the array is empty, for later use as in the answer.

```js
Array.prototype.randomSplice = function () {
    return this.length && this.splice(Math.random() * this.length | 0, 1) || undefined;
}

var wordList = [],
    data = {
        Apple: 'An apple a day',
        Bat: 'Out of hell',
        Car: 'So dirty',
        Dog: 'The best friend',
        Elephant: 'Remember the life'
    },
    words = Object.keys(data);

function getWord() {
    var word = words.randomSplice();
    if (word) {
        wordList.push(word);
        document.getElementById('word').innerHTML = word;
        document.getElementById('wordMeaning').innerHTML = data[word];
        document.getElementById('wordList').innerHTML = wordList.join(', ');
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="getWord();">Get Word</button>
<h3>Word</h3>
<div id="word"></div>
<h3>Meaning</h3>
<div id="wordMeaning"></div>
<h3>List</h3>
<div id="wordList"></div>
```